# Custom Varchar format to datetime

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have the data in the DB as 20170608_1345 for the date and time.I want to 
    get in the format of '2017-06-08 13:45'

Please advise if we have any conversion formats for this.

Comment: please add the version of SQL Server

Comment: dumbest way is to use bunch of `SUBSTRING` and concatenate them, if this is the constant format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `stuff()` to swap your underscore for a space, and insert a semicolon for the time:

```
create table t (str varchar(32));
insert into t values ('20170608_1345');

select convert(datetime,stuff(stuff(str,12,0,':'),9,1,' '))
from t
```

returns `2017-06-08 13:45:00`